Extract dominant value per column with single value per row in a matrix
Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n \times m}$ where $m \geq n$.
I want to convert it into a form where there is a single $1$ per row yet no more than a single $1$ per column.
The logic is convert the highest sum of values into 1.
For instance, for $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0.3 & 0.25 & 0.9 \\ 0.6 & 0.1 & 0.03 \end{bmatrix}$ the output will be $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.
So I'm after maximizing $\sum_{i, j} \left( A \otimes B \right)$ (where $\otimes$ is the element wise multiplication) under the constraints that $ {B}_{i, j} \in \left\{ 0, 1 \right\}$, $ \sum_{i} {B}_{i, j} = 1 \; \forall j$ and $\sum_{j} {B}_{i, j} \leq 1 \; \forall i$.
The problem arises when the maximum of several columns happens at the same row:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0.8 & 0.25 & 0.9 & 0.5 \\ 0.6 & 0.1 & 0.03 & 0.55 \\ 0.23 & 0.33 & 0.2 & 0.45 \end{bmatrix}$$
I am not after an optimal solution.
I'm OK with a greedy solution which is fast and near optimal.
Is this problem known? Are there known greedy algorithms for the case of large matrices?

I don't understand what you mean by "convert it".  What relationship must exist between the output matrix and $A$?  Can I just ignore every entry of $A$ and replace them with 1's and 0's however I like?  I don't understand what you mean by "the highest sum of values".  Can you express that using mathematics?  What does $\otimes$ represent?  Is it matrix multiplication?  Something else?  I encourage you to [edit] the question to make the problem clearer.

@D.W., $\otimes$ is the elementwise multiplication. I wrote the optimization problem. Yet I'm looking for a greedy solution as the optimal solution involves solving integer problem.

Your problem can be shown to be NP-hard.

 reduction from weighted maximum matching

Here is a greedy solution:
Step 0: Start with $B = \{0\}_{m\times n}$ and let $A' = A$
Step 1: Select the maximum value in the matrix $A'$
$$(i,j) \leftarrow \arg\max_{i,j} ~A'$$
Step 2: If $A'[i,j] == 0$ then STOP; else, put a mark in $B$ and clear the row and column in $A'$ i.e, $$B[i,j] = 1 \text{ and } A'[i:~] = A'[~:j] = 0$$
Step 3: Go to Step 1

Is there some analysis of the performance of this greedy approach to the optimal one?

Finding a performance guarantee seems to be a non-trivial research contribution in your case. You can look at these existing results: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707034

Thanks. I can't vote as I'm missing credit. So I can only mark.

It's okay, always happy to help :)
